# LEFT OUTER JOIN is expressed as just LEFT JOIN in MySql syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, left-join

Is `LEFT OUTER JOIN` expressed as just `LEFT JOIN` in MySQL syntax? Or are `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN` different things in MySQL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically they are the same.

`LEFT` and `RIGHT` are `outer` type join. The keyword `OUTER` is  optional, and what this means in this case is that whether you specify it or not makes no difference.

Additional Information,

At the top level there are mainly 3 types of joins:

- INNER
- OUTER (*LEFT*, *RIGHT*)
- CROSS

Comment: In other DBMSs but not in MySQL, there is also `FULL` (outer) join. In MySQL (and Postgres and a few others), there is also `NATURAL JOIN`.